# Why are solution explorer icon backgrounds not transparent?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, user-interface

I'm using the Visual Studio 2010 SexColor plugin to change the background color of the VS Solution Explorer. Unfortunately, there's an ugly white box around all the icons.

[image: Visual Studio Solution Explorer]

Does anyone have a suggestion on how I can fix this so the icons don't appear with the ugly white border? Is it a problem with the icons themselves, in that their backgrounds aren't transparent to begin with?

Answer (score 1):

It's the icons. They were designed for a flat white color, so to save space, they did away with transparency. Visual Studio 2012 uses transparency.

Comment: Any idea where those icons are so that I can modify them?